# Issue with Function templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a template function which can accept parameters say X or Y or Z. They are defined as follows:

```
typedef MyClassA< string > X;
typedef MyClassA< float > Y;
```

But classA itself is a template whose definition is as follows:

```
template< class T>
class MyClass
{

}
```

What should be my function signature in this case?
I tried a simple `func(T a)` but it failed.

Comment: Please post the actual code you tried, and the compiler error message(s).

Comment: Have you tried func(MyClass<T> a) ???

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you are after:

```
template< class T>
class MyClass
{

};
typedef MyClass< int > X;
typedef MyClass< float > Y;

template<class T>
void func(MyClass<T> a) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the usual syntax for template classes:

```
template <typename T>
class My
{
 public:
 void func(T c);
};

template <typename T>
void My<T>::func(T a)
{
 std::cout << "test\n";
}

int main()
{
  My<int> m;

  m.func(42);
}
```

and you should try this for template functions:

```
template <class T>
T func(T q) {
 return (++q);
}

int res = func<int>(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a function that will accept any specialisation of your class template as an argument? That would also have to be a template:

```
template <typename T> void func(MyClassA<T>);
```